# How to get value from different column using min value from another column

Tags: mysql

Here I have the following table, I want to get the value of product name using Minimum `P.price` as parameter after grouping and doing some calculation to get total qty.

```
+-----------------------------------+
|PO_Code |ProductName|P.Price |qty  |
|1122    |aaa        |800     | 3   |
|1122    |aaas       |643     | 5   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

what I want it's to make the table to be like this one

```
+----------------------------------------+
|PO_Code |ProductName|P.Price(MIN) |qty  |
|1122    |aaa        |800          | 8   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Thank you

Comment: aaas is different to aaa - why are they combined ?

Comment: those are sad column names Dicky

Comment: they are combined coz they have some po_code (purchase order code)